# How do I get the equation for this parabola in standard form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, conic-sections

How do I get the equation for this parabola in standard form?

$ y = f(x)= 2x^2+3x-2$

Comment: That's a pretty standard form already. Which particular "standard form" are you looking for?

Comment: the y=a(x-h)^2+k  form

Answer (score 1):

If you mean vertex form, you can complete the square.
$$\begin{align}f(x) &= 2x^2 + 3x - 2 \\
                    &= 2\left(x^2+\frac{3}{2}x\right) -2 \\
                    &= 2\left(x^2+\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{9}{16}-\frac{9}{16}\right) -2\\
                    &= 2\left(x^2 +\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{9}{16}\right) -2\left(\frac{9}{16}\right)-2\\
                    &= 2\left(x+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 - \frac{25}{8}\end{align}$$

Comment: okay I get that. how do i find if there are any intercepts or the min value?

Comment: Since $\left(x+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2$ is always positive, the minimum value of the function will occur when this expression is $0$, i.e. when $x = \frac{-3}{4}$. And when this happens, our vertex equation tells us that $f(-3/4) = \frac{-25}{8}$. To find $y$-intercepts, simply evaluate $f(0)$. To find $x$-intercepts, solve $2x^2 + 3x - 2 = 0$.